# How to compare bonds in terms of volume traded in Bloomberg Excel Add-in?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bloomberg, excel

I want to compare how much bonds of a handful of companies have been traded over the last years and pick the most traded bond for each company via the Excel add-in.

One example of what I have tried is the following:

```
=BDH("EJ070301 Corp";"VOLUME";"1/1/2010";"8/13/2018")
```

But it yields: N/A N/A.
I have also tried VOLUME, VWAP_VOLUME and PREVIOUS_TOTAL_VOLUME.
It does work with the data field function, i.e.

```
=BDP("EJ070301 Corp";"VOLUME")
```

What am I doing wrong or do you have a better suggestion?
As a related question, how can I get better at using Bloomberg via Excel, e.g. do you have link to a comprehensive handbook (one better than Bloomberg one if possible...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question the Helpdesk should be more than capable to answer. For Fixed Income generally you need to specify the source since volume data is often not available (exceptions: MIFID 2, TRACE or Exchange data).

```
=BDH("EJ070301 @MFTD Corp","PX_VOLUME","1/1/2010","8/13/2018")
```

Above will give you all MIFID 2 reported trade data YTD. VWAP is also not really meaningful for credit since data is so sparse.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it is not very practical to use the helpdesk for every single query, as it takes up to 2 business days. Hence also my question of whether there is a comprehensive handbook containing all details on the Excel add-in. Questions that I would now hope a handbook could answer are for example: how can I identify the right data source, or, if I have to try out all, which are all possible data sources? Also, as I wrote above, I am not sure which type of volume data is the right one for my purpose, is it VOLUME? (Not a suitable question for helpdesk I guess.)

Comment: They have a live chat so there is no delay. "VOLUME" is a real time field, "PX_VOLUME" is for historical data. You can check all the options on FLDS <GO> 

I'm not aware of any handbook I'm afraid.